# Por que os números "onze" ao "quinze" não se escreve como uma composição da dezena mais a unidade? Assim como ocorre do "dez-E-sseis" ao "dez-E-nove"

Tags: etimologia, números, prefixos

Os números, do 11 ao 15 são escritos da seguinte forma:

> onze
>   doze
>   treze
>   quatorze
>   quinze

Do 16 ao 19 da seguinte:

> dezesseis
>   dezessete
>   dezoito
>   dezenove

Reparem que do 16 em diante todos têm o prefixo `dez`, algo que ao meu ver é o mais intuitivo. Existe algum motivo para que do 11 ao 15 tenham escritas "especiais"?

Comment: Porque é que em inglês se diz _eleven_ e _twelve_? É apenas mais uma irregularidade na língua.

Comment: @someonewithpc acredito que todas as línguas românicas devem ter esse "problema", mas isso não impede de eu perguntar isso aqui.

Comment: Não, não impede, claro. Embora inglês não seja uma língua românica, mas sim anglo-saxônica.

Comment: Dezeum, dezedois, dezetrês, dezequatro, dezecinco, dezesseis, dezessete, dezeoito, dezenove, dezedez, dezeonze!

Comment: dezasseis, dezassete, dezoito, dezanove em Portugal.

Comment: @VictorStafusa dezeum -> dezeonze  ahahahahah

Comment: Esse "problema" é comum nas línguas românicas, mas ainda assim não é constante. O francês, por exemplo, muda entre a França e a Bélgica (pertinhos um do outro). O número `90` é dito *quatre-vingt-dix* na França (algo como 'quatro 20's mais 10') e *nonante* na Bélgica (algo mais próximo de 'noventa'). Parece que a influencia de outros povos, como os Celtas, afetou esse tipo de "preferência" na contagem, e imagino que o mesmo possa ter ocorrido com o português.

Comment: Aliás, [essa resposta no *french.se*](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1002), naturalmente em francês, é bem interessante (mesmo que se precise usar o Google Translator). :)

Comment: Resposta convertida para comentário: Esta é apenas mais uma (irritante) irregularidade da nossa língua, que ocorre também em muitas outras línguas próximas. Não sei qual a origem, mas a não ser que consiga convencer a maioria das pessoas a mudar, vai continuar a ser assim. :P

Línguas artificias como o Esperanto e o Lojban, que foram criadas para obter uma língua menos irregular não sofrem desta irregularidade.

Comment: Boa pergunta! (Relacionada com http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/why-do-eleven-and-twelve-get-unique-words-and-not-end-in-teen)

Comment: [A question about Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French on Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/latin-italian-spanish-portuguese-and-french-number-words-from-eleven-to-ninet)

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9811/707).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### PORTUGUÊS (English follows)

Quando se criam palavras para expressar quantidades numa determinada linguagem, primeiro por via oral e, posteriormente, por escrito, o sistema de numeração utilizado é normalmente baseado no ambiente cultural que envolve essa linguagem.

Muitas culturas usaram sistemas de numeração com base no número de dedos de uma ou ambas as mãos, e por vezes, até mesmo os dedos dos pés são considerados. Assim, os sistemas de numeração são baseados em 5, 10 ou 20.

Em certas culturas, os nomes utilizados para os números estiveram relacionados com os nomes dos dedos e das mãos. Podemos descobrir que "dígitos" provêm do latim "*digitus*" (dedo), enquanto "*pantcha*" (cinco em sânscrito) vem do persa "*pentcha*" (mão).

Os Tamanacos, uma tribo de índios sul-americanos, representavam os seguintes números da seguinte forma:

- 5 = "uma mão inteira";
- 6 = "um (dedo) na outra mão";
- 7 = "dois (dedos) na outra mão";
- 8 e 9 seguiam a mesma regra;
- 10 = "ambas as mãos";
- de 11 a 14, os Tarnanacos estendiam ambas as mãos e contavam "um (dedo) do pé", "dois (dedos) do pé" e assim sucessivamente;
- 15 = "um pé cheio".
- 16 = "um (dedo) do outro pé", e assim por diante até 19.
- 20 era representado por "um índio";
- 21 era "um (dedo) na mão desse outro índio";
- "Dois índios" significavam 40;
- "Três índios", 60...

Isto é um bom exemplo de um sistema de bases mistas para a numeração de 5 e 20.

O português, tal como outras línguas românicas, deriva do latim.
Os nomes latinos dos primeiros dez números ocorreram devido à base 10.

- 1 unus (um / uma)
- 2 duo (dois / duas)
- 3 tres (três)
- 4 quattuor (quatro)
- 5 quinque (cinco)
- 6 sex (seis)
- 7 septem (sete)
- 8 octo (oito)
- 9 novem (nove)
- 10 decem (dez)

No entanto, o sistema romano usava um sistema misto de base 5 e 10, com determinadas características que influenciaram a nomeação de seguinte números.

- 11 **un**de**cim** (onze)
- 12 **duo**de**cim** (doze)
- 13 **tre**de**cim** (treze)
- 14 **quattuor**de**cim** (quatorze ou catorze)
- 15 **quin**de**cim** (quinze)
- 16 **se**de**cim** (dezasseis ou dezesseis) Talvez deveria ter sido "seize"
- 17 **septen**de**cim** (dezassete ou dezessete) Talvez deveria ter sido "seteze"
- 18 **duo**de**viginti** (dezoito) poderia ser "doisparavinte"
- 19 **un**de**viginti** (dezanove ou dezenove) poderia ser "umparavinte"
- 20 viginti (vinte)

Isto deveu-se à notação romana "XIX" (um para 20).

Quando os Portugueses adotaram o uso de [algarismos arábicos](http://www.matematicasdigitales.com/wp-content/uploads/numeros.jpg) foi corrigido o uso de "20 menos um" e "20 menos dois".
Nesta evolução, foram encontradas variantes, como no espanhol e no português, em que os números foram preservados até 15, ou como no francês e no italiano, onde se preservou até 16. Podemos também encontrar alguma outra reminiscência, como o "vinte".

Curiosamente, algumas línguas modernas ainda têm algumas reminiscências do uso da base 20, como os "*quatre-vingts*" (80 em francês), ou "*fourscore*" (80 ou *eighty* em Inglês arcaico).

Perguntas relacionadas:

- Linguistics: [Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French number words from eleven to nineteen - Palavras para números 11-19 em latino, italiano, espanhol e francês - história de uma construção inconsistente e bizarro](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/latin-italian-spanish-portuguese-and-french-number-words-from-eleven-to-ninet)
- Em inglês: [Porque onze e doze têm palavras únicas e não terminam em "-teen"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/why-do-eleven-and-twelve-get-unique-words-and-not-end-in-teen)
- Em francês: [Treize, quatorze, quinze, seize](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/878/treize-quatorze-quinze-seize), também [De onde vêm soixante-dix e quatre-vingts (em vez de septante e huitante)?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/989/do%C3%B9-viennent-soixante-dix-et-quatre-vingts-plut%C3%B4t-que-septante-et-huitante/1002#1002)
- Em espanhol: [Qual é a origem dos nomes dos números?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-los-nombres-de-los-n%C3%BAmeros)
- Em italiano: [Palavras para números 11-19 em italiano - história de uma construção inconsistente e bizarro](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten)

---

### ENGLISH

When words are created to express quantities by a particular language, first orally and later written, the numbering system is commonly based on the cultural environment involving that language.

Many cultures have used numbering systems based on the number of fingers of one or both hands, and sometimes, even toes are considered. Thus, numbering systems are based on 5, 10 or 20.

In some cultures, the names used for the numbers were related to the names of the fingers and hands. For example "*dígitos*" comes from the Latin "*digitus*" (finger), while "*pantcha*" (five in Sanskrit) comes from the Persian "*pentcha*" (hand).

The Tamanacos, a tribe of South American Indians, represented their numbers in the following way:

- 5 = "an entire hand";
- 6 = "one on the other hand";
- 7 = "two on the other hand";
- 8 and 9 followed the same rule;
- 10 = "both hands"
- From 11 to 14, the Tarnanacos extended both hands and had "one (finger) in a foot" and "two (fingers) in a foot..." and so on up to 15.
- 15 = "a full foot";
- From 16 to 19 followed the same rule on the other foot;
- 20 would refer to "an Indian";
- 21 was "one (finger) in the hand of another Indian"
- "Two Indians" meant 40;
- "Three Indians", 60...

This is a good example of a system mixing bases 5 and 20.

Portuguese, like other Romanian languages, derives from Latin.
Latin had names for the first ten numbers because of the usage of the base 10.

- 1 unus (um / uma)
- 2 duo (dois / duas)
- 3 tres (três)
- 4 quattuor (quatro)
- 5 quinque (cinco)
- 6 sex (seis)
- 7 septem (sete)
- 8 octo (oito)
- 9 novem (nove)
- 10 decem (dez)

However, the Roman system for writing numbers used a mixed system of bases 5 and 10, with certain characteristics that influenced the naming of the following numbers:

- 11 **un**de**cim** (onze)
- 12 **duo**de**cim** (doze)
- 13 **tre**de**cim** (treze)
- 14 **quattuor**de**cim** (quatorze ou catorze)
- 15 **quin**de**cim** (quinze)
- 16 **se**de**cim** (dezasseis ou dezesseis) Maybe it would be "seize"
- 17 **septen**de**cim** (dezassete ou dezessete) Maybe it would be "seteze"
- 18 **duo**de**viginti** (dezoito) it would be "doisparavinte"
- 19 **un**de**viginti** (dezanove ou dezenove) it would be "umparavinte"
- 20 viginti (vinte)

This was due to the Roman notation "XIX" (one for 20).

When Portuguese adopted the use of [Arabic numerals](http://www.matematicasdigitales.com/wp-content/uploads/numeros.jpg), the use of "20 minus one" and "20 minus two" was corrected. In this evolution, variants were found, as in Spanish and Portuguese, in which numbers have been preserved up to 15, or as in French and Italian, these were preserved up to 16.

We can also find some other reminiscences, such as the "*vinte*" (20 in Portuguese). Interestingly, some modern languages still have some reminiscences of using the base 20, as the "*quatre-Vingts*" (80 in French), or "*fourscore*" (80 or eighty in archaic English).

Related questions:

- Linguistics: [Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French number words from eleven to nineteen - history of a bizarre, inconsistent construction](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/latin-italian-spanish-portuguese-and-french-number-words-from-eleven-to-ninet)
- English: [Why do eleven and twelve get unique words and not end in “-teen”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/why-do-eleven-and-twelve-get-unique-words-and-not-end-in-teen)
- French: [Treize, quatorze, quinze, seize](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/878/treize-quatorze-quinze-seize), also tangentially [Where do soixante-dix and quatre-vingts (instead of septante and huitante) comes from?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/989/do%C3%B9-viennent-soixante-dix-et-quatre-vingts-plut%C3%B4t-que-septante-et-huitante/1002#1002) (in french)
- Spanish: [What is the origin of the names of the numbers?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-los-nombres-de-los-n%C3%BAmeros)
- Italian: [Italian number words from eleven to nineteen - history of a bizarre, inconsistent construction](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/italian-number-words-from-eleven-to-nineteen-history-of-a-bizarre-inconsisten)

Comment: Português e Inglês não são línguas nativas para mim. Sinta-se livre para corrigir os erros. Portuguese and English are not native languages for me. Feel free to fix any mistakes.

Comment: Para quem não é nativo escreves muito bem em Português, melhor que muitos nativos.

Comment: Se não tivesse mencionado que o Português não é sua língua nativa eu nunca iria saber. Realmente muito bom.

Comment: That's interesting, but it doesn't explain why 16 and 17 are constructed as 10+x like 18 and 19, and not derived from the Latin.

Comment: @Gilles `variants were found, as in Spanish and Portuguese, in which numbers have been preserved up to 15, or as in French and Italian, these were preserved up to 16` that should explain about 16 (*seize* in french, *sedici* in italian). About 17, I guess it was just another government cuts :-D

Comment: Grande resposta, +1!